# The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher"

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I'm trying to get the sha1 key of my project but each time I do by the running, cd android and later gradlew signingReport, everything will run smoothly but at the end of the day I get this message "The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.5.20 and higher". It's a flutter project and I'm using android studio. Below is my android/build.gradle and also my app/build.gradle.

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.freejob.freejob"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.freejob.freejob"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies{
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.10"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics"

}
```

I upgraded my kotlin in the android/build.gradle to the lastest version 1.9.23. I also tried other kotlin version but I kept having the same problem.

Comment: I suspect it's an IDE problem. Try running `./gradlew` from command line: if there's no errors it's in your IDE. If so update your Kotlin plugin in the IDE and consider choosing option to use Gradle for building projects